# Constructor for a class containing a vec of vecs

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

I'm trying to learn how to create a class which properly initializes a vectors of vectors to implement a matrix. The code below doesn't work, after running the constructor the vector has size 0. The program prints 0 and attempts to access elements of it result in errors.

1. My first question is what is wrong with the code and how to fix it.
2. My second question is if there is a better approach to creating a class to implement a matrix dynamically using vectors or similar objects from the STL.

Code:

```
class Matrix{
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > Mat;
public:
    Matrix(int n, int m);
    void set(int a, int b, int Value);
    int get(int a, int b);
    void size();
};

Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > Mat(n, vector<int>(m));
}

void Matrix::size(){
    std::cout << std::endl << Mat.size() << std::endl;
}

int Matrix::get(int a, int b){
return Mat[a][b];
}

void Matrix::set(int a, int b, int Value){
    Mat[a][b]=Value;
}


int main(int argc, char** argv) {

  Matrix M(10,10);
  M.size();  

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can format code easily with the `{}` button.

Comment: @tadman Not that easy after a list.

Comment: Are you sure you need a nested `vec` structure? You can emulate a two dimensional array by creating a single array of size m*n and reference `Mat[a + b*n]` instead.

Comment: In the constructor you initialize a local variable with the same name as the class attribute.

Comment: Just for my future reference, how do you format code after a list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1) Current code**

The problem is that `Mat` is already constructed when you enter the body of your constructor.  What you do is just redefine a local `Mat` which hides the member having the same name and which vanishes as soon as you exit the constructor.

Try this instead:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m) : Mat(n, vector<int>(m)) {
}
```

**2)Are there better approaches ?**

it all depend on what you intend to do, whar atre your constraints, and what are the trade-offs:

- If the size of you matrixes is not always defined at compile time, this kind of implementation is fairly good, and the code very readable.
- If you have many rather small vectors, one alternative could be to flatten the internal representation of the matrix to a unidimensional vector.  You'd spare some vectors, but have to calculate the flatened index for the getter and the setter.  If your Matrix class would provide a lot of matrix operations, would make the code less readable (i.e. `Mat[n][m]` vs. `Mat[n*width+m]`)
- If the size of your matrix is determined at compile time (e.g. you use only 2D or 3D matrixes), it could make sense to use `std::array` instead of `std::vector`: the compiler could then make use of the known sizes to generate faster code.

Comment: I've never seen the syntax for a function / constructor before. Can you explain what is going on or point to a reference?

Comment: @Joe It is the same syntax than the constructor that you used in your body.  The difference is that if you put it after the `:` following the constructor you indicate the constructor parameters to be used (i.e. Mat is not created and changed in the body, but it's created directly with the right arguments).  This syntax is only for constructors

Comment: @Joe The stuff at the beginning of the following link will look crazy, but it's hard to define this stuff without it looking crazy. Skip down to Explanation and it does a pretty good plain-English job of translating the High Geek used in the opening and covers what you probably need to know about Member Initializer Lists. They are a very powerful and handy tool that doesn't get neatly enough coverage in school or most texts. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list

Answer (score 2):

This code:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m){
    std::vector<std::vector<int> > Mat(n, vector<int>(m));
}
```

will default construct the member-variable `Mat`, and then, separately, try to construct a local variable `Mat`, unrelated to the member. To initialize the member variable, you'll want to use a member initializer list:

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m)
    : Mat(n, std::vector<int>(m))
{ }
```

---

As a side-note, `size()` should *return* the size, not print it, and if your getter returned an `int&` instead of an `int`, you wouldn't need a setter with the code duplication.

Answer (score -1):

in the constructor you should initialize using the following instead

```
Matrix::Matrix(int n, int m) {
   Mat = std::vector<std::vector<int> > (n, std::vector<int>(m));
}
```

or use the way mentioned in the other answers

Comment: The Member Initializer List approach is vastly superior to this. This may result in `Mat` having been constructed empty, a temporary `vector` being constructed, and that temp `vector` being copied into `Mat`. And maybe less work, depending on the compiler and options set. Regardless, the Initializer List will get the whole job done in one shot.

Comment: I won't say it is vastly superior to this but it may give a slightly better performance than my method. However, considering the OP is using built-in non-const and non-reference types, it will achieve the same result

Comment: @Thesane So best-case, this solution is more verbose and slower. Worst-case, it doesn't work at all?

Comment: I don't know where it won't work at all? can you please explain. Second, slower by how much ? do you have some metrics or link to explain more? thanks

Comment: @Thesane Like you already mentioned - it wouldn't work at all if the member were `const` or a reference.

Comment: that's completely out of the scope of question. OP isn't using const or reference. So this solution will (and was working) work all the times for this particular problem!!

Comment: @Thesane Hence my initial comment - best-case (i.e. this case), the solution is more verbose (and potentially slower) than the proposed answers. Worst-case (i.e. for different types of members), it's a non-starter. There are only disadvantages to this approach.

Comment: both ways have pros/cons. for example you can't use initialization list if you want to try/catch the values before assigning it or they have be initialized in specific order or if you want to do operations on the values before assigning or test range or or or and the list continues. we aren't making a tutorial about every case possible. I am answering a specific question and my answer is correct for this question and might be even more applicable in case OP want for example to create vectors only bigger than 0. I don't understand why all the fuzz but I am done discussing it anymore.